# Google Ruby API client - "Missing required parameters: id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

I'm attempting to use the Google Ruby API client to call the Drive API to get a file's metadata, and I'm receiving the error "Missing required parameters: id." Here's the code -- what am I doing wrong? (Note: client id and secret are working fine for requesting access tokens, etc. And the error is "id", not "client id" or "file id").

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
drive = client.discovered_api('drive')

client.authorization.client_id = ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"]
client.authorization.client_secret = ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
client.authorization.redirect_uri = "http://..."
client.authorization.access_token = "..."

client.authorization.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => drive.files.get,
  :version => 'v2',
  :parameters => { 'fileId' => "..."}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out. The call to discovered_api was missing the version number. Should be:

```
drive = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')
```

Comment: i'm getting the same error and i'm not missing the version number.